# How do you get out of infinite loop when there's no match?

Tags: c#, .net, file, while-loop

So I'm trying to test my validations of when a user types in the wrong 5 digit number then it will display an error and go back to the original form. However, my code makes the code go into an infinite loop so I'm unable to do anything else on my form since the loop never ends.

```
public bool findCustomer(string accountNumber)
{
    string record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord();                 //gets first record
    bool okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);   //checks if it matches
    while (!okay == true)                                                       //if it does not match, get next record and check again until it reaches end of file
    {
         record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord();      
         okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
    }

        return okay;                                                                                  
}//end method
```

Here is the get record method from another class

```
public string getNextRecord()
{
    string nextRecord = String.Empty;

    while ((nextRecord = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        return nextRecord;
    }

        return nextRecord;
    }// end getNextRecord
```

Here is the textfile

```
 12345 * Shrek * 1209 * 100000 * 50000
 12077 * Sammy Wheeler * 1207 * 5000 * 0
 99999 * The Big Grump * 1298 * 1500000 * 1500000
 13579 * Brooks Robinson * 5555 * 225000  * 225000
 24680 * Johnny Unitas * 1919 * 60000 * 34000
 68420 * Y. A. Tittle * 1414 * 42000 * 12000
 23456 *  Hilary Clinton * 2222  * 65000 * 123456
 23232 * Julianne Baird * 1234  * 145000 * 12321
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use a database system. If you need to store your records in a file, go for SQLite. Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the case where `getNextRecord()` returns null or empty string

```
while (!okay)                                                       
{
     record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord();   
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record)
         break;   
     okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
}
```

Notice that if the file contains an empty string in the middle of it's data then this will fail and lines after that empty line will be escaped.

Why checking for both `null` and `string.Empty`? Because if reader reaches end of file then `nextRecord` is null.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, no next record means that you will return `string.Empty`:

```
public string getNextRecord()
{
    string nextRecord = String.Empty;

    while ((nextRecord = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        return nextRecord;
    }

        return nextRecord;
}// end getNextRecord
```

You could simply use this info to get out from your loop:

```
record = "initval";
while (!okay == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(record))                                                       //if it does not match, get next record and check again until it reaches end of file
{
     record = Global.currentFile.getNextRecord();      
     okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
}
```

Nevertheless, you could simplify your code further still by removing the `getNextRecord()` out and changing `!okay == true` to `!okay`:

```
public bool findCustomer(string accountNumber)
{
    string record = reader.ReadLine(); //gets first record
    bool okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);   //checks if it matches
    while (!okay && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(record))                                                       //if it does not match, get next record and check again until it reaches end of file
    {
         record = reader.ReadLine(); //why not this?
         if (record != null)  
             okay = Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, record);
    }

        return okay;                                                                                  
}//end method
```

Comment: You should check for both null and empty value of `record`.

Comment: `!okay == true` is totally wrong.. `!okay` will take care of your problem. Ok, maybe not all of it but it seams to be very important to point out by several posters.

Comment: @hylander0 actually, it is more of *redundant* than *important*. :) but for some people, getting rid of redundancy *is* important. Thus it *is* important.

Comment: @hylander0 for the same reasoning, I got rid of the function `getNextRecord` because it is... *redundant* ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, a lil advice `(!okay == true)`  is the same as `(!okay)`, just personal preference. Regarding the code, IMO, you never check if you have finnished reading the file. When there are no more records, you simply return "" and your code keeps calling `Global.customer.matchCustomer(accountNumber, "");` which always returns false, therefore, infinite loop. Consider `while (!okay && record != String.Empty)`